# Getting SSL error while making API call mostly TLS ver mismatch

Tags: python, ssl, twilio

I'm trying to call a API and in return I'm getting `SSL` error which most likely because of `TLS` version mismatch. Please guide me what needs to be done to make it work.

> `    import ssl

```
  from twilio.rest import Client

  accountSID = 'xxxxxx'
  authToken = 'xxxxxxx
  twilioCli = Client(accountSID, authToken)
  myTwilioNumber = '+14955551234'
  myCellPhone = 'xxxxxxxx'
  message = twilioCli.messages.create(body='Mr.Ankit - you are doing great.', from_=myTwilioNumber, to=myCellPhone)

   print(message.sid)`
```

Python code generates error:

> "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twilio.com', port=443): Max
>   retries exceeded with url:
>   /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC1f7769b1600b53ae66ebd6a7c4cd1b92/Messages.json
>   (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))"

`SSL` version 1.1

`Python` version is 3.7

Comment: Can you please provide the sample script you are trying to run?

Comment: import ssl
from twilio.rest import Client



#print(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23


accountSID = 'xxxxxxxx'
authToken = 'xxxxxxxxx'
twilioCli = Client(accountSID, authToken)
myTwilioNumber = '+14955551234'
myCellPhone = '+91xxxxxxxxx'
message = twilioCli.messages.create(body='Mr.Ankit - you are doing great.', from_=myTwilioNumber, to=myCellPhone)

print(message.sid)

Comment: Put the script *in* the question as *formatted code* (after pasting the code, select the code and enter ctrl-k).

Comment: I've updated code in my orignal post. Thank you

Comment: This post says to update your system's certificate. See this if it helps: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007853433-Troubleshooting-Certificate-Errors-from-the-Twilio-REST-API